# Is there any way to turn off the automatically opening window for a preview in Marsedit?

Tags: preferences

Whenever I open a post to edit it a whole preview window opens up along with it. I find this effect disorienting. I looked in the preferences and couldn't find anything. How do I shut off the automatic opening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - this is a per blog preference.

I found [this on the Mars Edit support page](http://www.red-sweater.com/forums/discussion/comment/9547/#Comment_9547)...

1. Double click the blog in the main window to open settings.
2. Click the "Editing" pane.
3. Find the "Preview Defaults" at the bottom of that section.

Here's a picture showing that you can choose to have it off or remember the last state as well as the default option of opening.

[image]